# Change storage class of (existing) objects in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, gsutil

I recently learnt of the new storage tiers and reduced prices announced on the Google Cloud Storage platform/service.

So I wanted to change the default storage class for one of my buckets from Durable Reduced Availability to Coldline, as that is what is appropriate for the files that I'm archiving in that bucket.

I got this note though:

> Changing the default storage class only affects objects you add to this bucket going forward. It does not change the storage class of objects that are already in your bucket.

Any advice/tips on how I can change class of all existing objects in the bucket (using Google Cloud Console or `gsutil`)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The easiest way to synchronously move the objects to a different storage class in the same bucket is to use [rewrite](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/rewrite). For example, to do this with gsutil, you can run:

```
gsutil -m rewrite -s coldline gs://your-bucket/**
```

Note: make sure gsutil is up to date (version 4.22 and above support the `-s` flag with `rewrite`).

Alternatively, you can use the new `SetStorageClass` action of the [Lifecycle Management](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle) feature to asynchronously (usually takes about 1 day) modify storage classes of objects in place (e.g. by using a `CreatedBefore` condition set to some time after you change the bucket's default storage class).

Comment: This is the easiest way to synchronously move the objects to a different storage class in the same bucket. Alternatively, you can use the new SetStorageClass action of the Lifecycle Management feature to asynchronously (usually takes about 1 day) modify storage classes of objects in place (e.g., by using a CreatedBefore condition set to some time after you change the bucket's default storage class): https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle

Comment: Thank you, Travis, Jeff; appreciate it!

**Works like a charm** ☺, although **the operation overwrites the Creation & Update times!**

I had two follow-up queries:

 1. Is `gsutil rewrite` operation billable?
 2. Can Creation time be preserved?

Many thanks.

Cheers!

fynali

Comment: Yes, it is billable as a Class A operation (it uses storage.objects.rewrite, see https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing).  No, there's no way to preserve the creation/update time because rewrite creates a new object generation.

Comment: Done! Changed storage class of 29,459 DRA objects to Coldline; cost < ¢30!

Comment: Using Object Lifecycle Management does preserve the creation/update time.
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle


This blog post covers setting Lifecycle rules on a Cloud Storage bucket to change the storage class of files over time so that their storage price costs less:
https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/scheduling-cloud-sql-exports-using-cloud-functions-and-cloud-scheduler#:~:text=Cloud%20Storage%20Object%20Lifecycle%20Management

Comment: For me with zsh and GCP bucket level access enabled to command that worked was `gsutil rewrite -O -s nearline 'gs:/your-bucket/**'`

Comment: I got `CommandException: 21933 files/objects could not be rewritten` and solved it by adding the `-O` flag. Needed if the bucket has uniform access control (no object-level ACLs).

Answer (score 5):

To change the storage class from NEARLINE to COLDLINE, create a JSON file with the following content:

```json
{
  "lifecycle": {
    "rule": [
      {
        "action": {
          "type": "SetStorageClass",
          "storageClass": "COLDLINE"
        },
        "condition": {
          "matchesStorageClass": [
            "NEARLINE"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Name it `lifecycle.json` or something, then run this in your shell:

```
$ gsutil lifecycle set lifecycle.json gs://my-cool-bucket
```

The changes may take up to 24 hours to go through. As far as I know, this change will not cost anything extra.

Comment: this is the best answer today

Comment: You can also create this rule in the dashboard UI. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle-configurations#change_an_objects_storage_class

Comment: This answer is good but it only works from one class to a "colder" one. For example, COLDINE to STANDARD is impossible currently.

Comment: This operation DOES cost, it's a Class A operation on the target storage class (it uses storage.objects.rewrite, see cloud.google.com/storage/pricing).

Answer (score 2):

I did this:

`gsutil -m rewrite -r -s <storage-class> gs://my-bucket-name/`

(-r for recursive, because I want all objects in my bucket to be affected).

Comment: I needed to add a -O because I use bucket level permissions.
So in the end my command becomes:


`gsutil -m rewrite -O -r -s <storage-class> gs://my-bucket-name/etc`

Answer (score 1):

You could now use "Data Transfer" to change a storage class by moving your bucket objects to a new bucket.

Access this from the left panel of Storage.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you couldn't access to the gsutil console, as in Google Cloud Function environment because Cloud Functions server instances don't have gsutil installed. Gsutil works on your local machine because you do have it installed and configured there. For all these cases I suggest you to evaluate the update_storage_class() blob method in python. This method is callable when you retrieve the single blob (in other words it refers to your specific object inside your bucket). Here an example:

```
from google.cloud import storage

storage_client = storage.Client()

blobs = storage_client.list_blobs(bucket_name)

for blob in blobs:
    print(blob.name)
    print(blob.storage_class)

all_classes = ['NEARLINE_STORAGE_CLASS', 'COLDLINE_STORAGE_CLASS', 'ARCHIVE_STORAGE_CLASS', 'STANDARD_STORAGE_CLASS', 'MULTI_REGIONAL_LEGACY_STORAGE_CLASS', 'REGIONAL_LEGACY_STORAGE_CLASS']

new_class = all_classes[my_index]
update_storage_class(new_class)
```

References:

- Blobs / Objects documentation: https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.update_storage_class
- Storage classes: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/storage-classes